# DDD: Domain model namespaces convention

Tags: php, namespaces, domain-driven-design, naming-conventions, namespace-organisation

I'm writing an application with a domain model in PHP, and am wondering which naming convention I should adopt.

Let's say I have a `Customer`, having an `Address` within its aggregate root.

I also have a `Product`, having an `Option` within its aggregate root.

I have two alternatives:

1. Keep aggregate roots at the root of the domain model:

   ```
   Customer
   Customer\Address
   Product
   Product\Option
   ```

   **Pro**: I can use both `Customer` and `Product` in the same namespace

   **Con**: `Customer` has to reference its own `Address` as `Customer\Address`
2. Group all aggregate classes in the same namespace, *including* the aggregate root:

   ```
   Customer\Customer
   Customer\Address
   Product\Product
   Product\Option
   ```

   **Pro**: `Customer` can reference its address as `Address`

   **Con**: from my root domain namespace, I have to reference:

   - `Customer` as `Customer\Customer`
   - `Product` as `Product\Product`

Comment: It's an interesting questions. Would be nice to hear how other people have solved it. Hopefully we'll see some answers soon, Benjamin :-)

Comment: Starting a bounty, hoping to get more resources on the subject! :-)

Comment: One thing that crossed my mind (perhaps off-topic): `namespaces` are specially usefull when projects are big in dimension, and / or when there's a lot of people involved in their development / maintenance. The basic principle of `DDD` is to keep everything simple and to the point, wich means that there will hardly exist any type of colisions inside the appliction. So .. are `namespaces` real necessary in this case?

Comment: @yoda: that's a good question, however the app we're working on currently consists of several dozen classes, so yes, we're really happy to have namespaces to organize the code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a little framework a while ago and i choose to use the first solution you propose.

> Keep aggregate roots at the root of the domain model:

Why?

Actually I asked myself the same question you're asking today and after a bit of discussion with my team mates we agreed that it felt more logical not to repeat the class name in the namespace.

---

**Let's see how to instanciate your classes with solution n°2**

```
Customer\Customer
Customer\Address
```

You will have to write :

```
$customer = new Customer\Customer();
$address = new Customer\Address();
```

You can see the repetition right? It kind of doesn't feel right to me. 
In my opinion it's like writing

```
$customer->getCustomerId();
```

Why repeat Customer in the method name? We know it's the customer's id since we're using a Customer object.

Another "bad thing" with this model is the impossibility to use reserved keyword as class name.

For exemple, using the pear convention you could have had the class

```
Customer_Abstract
```

Located at Customer/Abstract.php which is ok to me but if you try to translate it using namespace you will have

```
namespace Customer;

class Abstract {}
```

which results in a fatal error. So again you will have to repeat the domain in the class name :

```
namespace Customer;

class AbstractCustomer {}

$customer = new Customer\AbstractCustomer();
```

---

**Now let's see how to instanciate your classes with solution n°1**

```
Customer
Customer\Address
```

You will write :

```
$customer = new Customer();
$address = new Customer\Address();
```

We don't have to repeat Customer twice anymore to instanciate the Customer class. However it is still clear that Address is related to Customer.

That's why I choose to use this model.

EDIT : [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Home) use this convention too

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it looks like ZF2 actually uses the exact **opposite** approach: `Zend\Form\Form`, `Zend\Mail\Mail`, etc. They aim to pack each component in a single directory.

Comment: You're right. I didn't look at all the code. I saw Zend\Controller\Router, Zend\Controller\Router\Route and I didn't look further. My bad.

Comment: Ok, I thought we would have more reading on this question, but that probably means that it's just a matter of personal preference, not "best practices". What we'll end up with, will be to put only the aggregate roots at the root of the domain model namespace, and all their child entities in a namespace with the corresponding name. If the aggregate root is an abstract class, concrete classes subclassing it will be in the subnamespace as well.